# In phonegap app, How to display the multiple images selected from the gallery in an html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing a drag and drop app using phonegap.

There are 2 functions selImages() and loadImages()

```
function selImages() {
    window.imagePicker.getPictures(
        function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            img_arr[i] = results[i];
            ....
        }
        function loadImage() {
            var img_r2 = document.createElement('img');
            img_r2.src = img_arr[2];
            document.getElementById('loadImgDiv2').appendChild(img_r2);
        }
```

To execute these fns. in a single click:

```
function loadImage()
{
   selImages()
   //followed by the contents of loadImage fn....
}
```

[3 divs horizontally placed . images not seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyyyj.png)

pl. help

Comment: You will get image uri in results[i]. In that for loop, try to add img tag dynamically to display multiple images.

Comment: thank you so much. it works..